# Default Grafana K8s app PV issue: FailedBinding persistentvolume-controller no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

I am simply trying to deploy this Grafana app as-is, no changes to the YAML have been made: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/installation/kubernetes/

VMs are **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**. The Kubernetes cluster is made up of the Control-Plane/Mstr & 3x Worker nodes:

```
root@k8s-master:~# kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS   ROLES           AGE     VERSION
k8s-master    Ready    control-plane   35d     v1.24.2
k8s-worker1   Ready    worker          4h24m   v1.24.2
k8s-worker2   Ready    worker          4h24m   v1.24.2
k8s-worker3   Ready    worker          4h24m   v1.24.2v
```

Other K8s Pods such as NGINX run without issue.

However, the Grafana pod cannot start and is stuck in a Pending state:

```
root@k8s-master:~# kubectl create -f grafana.yaml
persistentvolumeclaim/grafana-pvc created
deployment.apps/grafana created
service/grafana created
# time passed here...
root@k8s-master:~# kubectl get pods
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE
grafana-9bd5bbd6b-k7ljz             0/1     Pending   0              3h39m
```

Troubleshooting this, I found there is an issue with the storage PersistentVolumeClaim (the `pvc`):

```
root@k8s-master:~# kubectl get pvc
NAME          STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
grafana-pvc   Pending                                                     2m22s
root@k8s-master:~#
root@k8s-master:~# kubectl describe pvc grafana-pvc
Name:          grafana-pvc
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       grafana-9bd5bbd6b-k7ljz
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age                  From                         Message
  ----    ------         ----                 ----                         -------
  Normal  FailedBinding  6s (x11 over 2m30s)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

Comment: Please refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73147599/default-grafana-k8s-app-pv-issue-failedbinding-persistentvolume-controller-no-p) that has been answered here.